# Exporting/saving a table of Interpolated functions

Tags: export, dumpsave

I have a lot of interpolated functions that I have generated from a numerical integral. It takes me 2 hours or so to generate them so I would prefer to save and import them.

I have tried `Export[...]` and `DumpSave[...]`. `DumpSave[...]` works for a single `Interpolation[...]` ut not for a table of them.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to export a table of interpolated functions?

Comment: ` DumpSave[…,{ip1,ip2,...}]` works for a list of interpolation functions too!

Comment: Hmm...I better check my code, thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann How can I actually use the functions? I think I was able to use `DumpSave` as you suggest, but when I import it with `Get` I can't figure out a way to use it. Could you provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

guidance to your comment:

define some user functions `sin,cos`

```
data
```

= Table[{x, Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50]}];
sin = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 2}]]];
cos = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 3}]]];

save the functions

```
DumpSave["sincos.mx", {sin, cos}]
```

Clear[sin,cos] (* new session*)

load function

```
Get["sincos.mx"]
```

now the loaded functions are available

```
Plot[{sin[x], cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

That's it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this, especially as strictly speaking it's out of the original question scope. If I want to pick the i'th object when using `Get` is that possible, so in your example say I only want to deal with/use `sin`.

Comment: @Q.P. Ulrich’s answer seems to be exactly what you are looking for. If you’re keen on Importing only one element from the list which you’ve dumpsaved, that is seemingly a different question dealing with different functionality & goals etc than what you posed. If you only want to use one function from your `DumpSave`, in your example of wanting only `sin`, you would call only `sin`, then. Perhaps you may `DumpSave` a list, say `trigfuncs={sin, cos}` for example, then call this by `trigfuncs[[i]]` where `i=1` for `sin`, but this is seemingly less functionality.

Comment: @CATrevillian Thanks for your helpful hint. Additional one could use`Names["Global`*"]` (before and after `Get`) to get the list of dumpsaved functions.